# Block IP address from Google adwords with their API

Tags: google-ads-api

Does anyone know how to block certain IP addresses from our Google adwords account using the Google API?

In [this article](http://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2456098?hl=en) you can see how to do it manually, but I cannot find a way to do it programmatically.

Comment: I am also looking for it. Found it?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's late. But I needed it as well.
I found the `IpBlock` type on Google AdWords [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201506/CampaignCriterionService.IpBlock).

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code i found, and improved slightly
require_once this code, then make this call for each campaign u want to ban the IP for

```
YourNameSpace\BlockedIP::add($campaignId, $ip);
```

voila

```
<?php
/*
    ...
*/

namespace YourNameSpace;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignCriterionService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\IpBlock;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\NegativeCampaignCriterion;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignCriterionOperation;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Operator;

class BlockedIP {
  public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
        AdWordsSession $session,
        $campaignId,
        $ip) {

    $campaignCriterionService =
        $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignCriterionService::class);


    $campaignCriteria = [];

    // Add a negative campaign criterion.
    $ipBlock = new IpBlock();
    $ipBlock->setIpAddress($ip);
    $negativeCriterion = new NegativeCampaignCriterion();
    $negativeCriterion->setCampaignId($campaignId);
    $negativeCriterion->setCriterion($ipBlock);

    $operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();
    $operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
    $operation->setOperand($negativeCriterion);
    $operations[] = $operation;

    $result = $campaignCriterionService->mutate($operations);

    // Print out some information about added campaign criteria.
    foreach ($result->getValue() as $campaignCriterion) {
      printf(
          "Campaign targeting criterion with ID %d and type '%s' was added.\n",
          $campaignCriterion->getCriterion()->getId(),
          $campaignCriterion->getCriterion()->getType());
    }
  }

  public static function add($campaignId, $ip) {
    // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->build();

    // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the OAuth2
    // credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();

    self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session, $campaignId, $ip);
  }
}
```